# Find orthonormal pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$, if $Ax_1=\alpha x_1+\beta x_2$ and $-By_1=\alpha y_1+\beta y_2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Given $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Lets define the following set (Davis-Wielandt shell):

$$DW(A):=\{(x^*Ax,x^*A*Ax) \mid x\in\mathbb{C^n},\|x\|_2=1\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}\sim\mathbb{R}^3.$$

> Assume that $DW(A)\cap DW(-B)$ is nonempty, then there are orthogonal
> pairs $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{C^n}$ and $(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb{C^n}$ such
> that  $$Ax_1=\alpha x_1+\beta x_2\qquad\text{and}\qquad -By_1=\alpha
> y_1+\beta y_2.$$
>
> with $(\alpha, \alpha^2+\beta^2)\in DW(A)\cap DW(-B)$. Suppose $U$ is unitary with $x_1,x_2$ as its first two columns, and $V$ is unitary with $y_1,y_2$ as its first two columns. Then $U^*AU+V^*BV$ has zero first column.

I want to construct these $U$ and $V$. I know $A,B,\alpha,\beta$. And also I know that $DW(A)$ is convex set.

---

My attempt:

From $Ax_1=\alpha x_1+\beta x_2$ we can get $\frac{A-\alpha I}{\beta}x_1=Cx_1=x_2$. Then we need to find $x_1$ such that the following three equations hold: $\|x_1\|=1$, $\|Cx_1\|=1$, $x_1^*x_2=0$.

If $C=U\Sigma V^*$ has singular values $\sigma_{max}>1$ and $\sigma_{max}<1$, then one possible way to construct $x_1$ might be $x_1=V[\sqrt{\frac{1-\sigma_{min}^2}{\sigma_{max^2}-\sigma_{min}^2}}\quad0\quad\cdots\quad0\quad \sqrt{1-\frac{1-\sigma_{min}^2}{\sigma_{max^2}-\sigma_{min}^2}}]^T.$

Then both $\|x\|=1$ and $\|Cx\|=1$ but I don't think $x_1^*x_2=0$ is satisfied. And also this procedure won't work when $C$ has all singular values larger than 1.

If I can get correct $x_1$ and $x_2$, then by using the following Matlab code I can get $U$:

```
U = [x1,x2,null([x1,x2]')]
```

Comment: By orthonormal pairs, do you mean $x_1$ is orthonormal to $x_2$ (and $y_1$ is orthonormal to $y_2$), or that $(x_1,x_2)$ is orthonormal to $(y_1,y_2)$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire $x_1$ is orthonormal to $x_2$

Comment: Ok, so why did you say that $x_1$ may not be orthonormal to $x_2$ in your attempt?

Comment: Because I am choosing $x_2$, not finding it exactly. So I am not sure if in that case I will get correct $x_1$, which must be orthonormal to $x_2$

Comment: We can get round the invertibility issue by letting $C=(A-\alpha I)/\beta$ so that $x_2=Cx_1$. Orthonormality means that $\langle x_1,Cx_1\rangle=0$ and $\|x_1\|=\|Cx_1\|=1$ so we can choose $x_1$ and hence $x_2$ quite freely.

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand how we can choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ freely. We need to choose $x_1$ so that $\|x_1\|=1$ and $\|Cx_1\|=1$ simultaneously. Given $C$, how to make sure $x_1$ satisfy both equations?

Comment: The question has several problems. One is that it should start giving the assumptions, not mention them as an afterthought. Is there really no assumption at all on $B$ apart from being $n\times n$? (For instance $B=0$ does seem difficult). Also "_if_ the following... hold" should probably be "_such that_ the following... hold", as the equations involve the pairs that are yet to be constructed.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks for your comment, I have edited the question including the quote from original source and my exact objective

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem solvable. Consider e.g., the case $A=2I_n$ ($I_n$ is the identity matrix) andd $\alpha=0, \beta=1$. Clearly, $A,\alpha$ and $\beta$ fulfill your assumptions. However, for any $x_1$ with $\|x_1\|=1$ we have $2x_1=Ax_1\stackrel{!}{=} \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 = \beta x_2$, thus $\|x_2\|=2$ and it is impossible to find an orthonormal pair $(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: I think we are also meant to determine conditions on $A,B,\alpha,\beta$ for orthonormality. For instance, $A,B$ cannot be positive definite.

Comment: thanks for pointing for that, I have edited the problem formulation +1